# Is Not Null Scope Causing Errors in PSQL Rails App

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a rails app running on heroku, for some reason the following scope is causing a lot of trouble and throws an error in PSQL ('rating' is an integer):

```
scope :rated, where("posts.rating <>''")
```

So naturally I tried everything listed below; these don't cause any errors, but the posts with null rating values STILL show up.

```
scope :rated, where("posts.rating IS NOT ?", nil)
scope :rated, where("posts.rating > 0")
scope :rated, where("posts.rating IS NOT NULL")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about combining them?

```
scope :rated, where("posts.rating IS NOT NULL AND posts.rating > 0")
```

Comment: ugh still returns posts with blank values

Comment: @BTHarris whats the sql generated by this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your third option above should work for standard PSQL, but you can also try:

```
posts.rating <> NULL or
posts.rating NOTNULL
```

Comment: And you can combine them with the NULLIF function: NULLIF(posts.rating, 0) NOTNULL